# Why does "none" come up when using time.sleep?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import time
import random

print "Wanna play a game?"

raw_input(),\
time.sleep(1)
print ("Think of a number (1-5), I won't see, I promise. \n"),\
    time.sleep(5)

print "You picked? Now write it down."
raw_input(),\
time.sleep(3)

print ("Let me guess... \n"),\
    time.sleep(2)

print ((random.randint(1, 5))), \
    time.sleep(20000)
```

When I run it in terminal, this happens:

```
Wanna play a game?

yes
Think of a number (1-5), I won't see, I promise. 
None
You picked? Now write it down.
Let me guess... 
None
1
```

Why does "none" pop up?

Comment: Why did you add those commas in your `print` statements?

Comment: Because you're passing the output of `time.sleep` (which is `None`) as the second thing to `print`. You really shouldn't be learning Python 2 at this point either.

Comment: Don't use python 2 lol

Comment: Because `time.sleep(5)` returns `None`, and you are printing it. As an aside, you **really** should not be using Python 2.

Comment: My guess is that you're using an IDE. The comma is a typo and when you pressed enter the IDE automatically inserted the line continuation ``\`` which caused the `sleep` to be part of the `print` even though you haven't intended that

Answer (score 0):

The `,\` in your code adding a new argument to the print statements and printing it, which in this case is the return value of `time.sleep()` (`None`)

Remove those, fix the indentation, and it works.

```
import time
import random

print "Wanna play a game?"

raw_input()
time.sleep(1)
print ("Think of a number (1-5), I won't see, I promise. \n")
time.sleep(5)

print "You picked? Now write it down."
raw_input()
time.sleep(3)

print ("Let me guess... \n")
time.sleep(2)

print ((random.randint(1, 5)))
time.sleep(20000)
```

Output:

```
Wanna play a game?
y
Think of a number (1-5), I won't see, I promise. 
You picked? Now write it down.
1
Let me guess... 
3
```

Comment: Because the OP is using Python 2, where `print` is a statement and not a function